# open cmd from batch-script, run command and close the previously opened terminal

Tags: batch-file, cmd, terminal

I made a small terminal menu where I can run several terminal commands in a new cmd.

Here a very compressed example:

```
    SET /P env=your conda env:    
    ...
    ECHO 2 - Run Rasa Action Server
    ...
    IF %M%==2 GOTO RUN_RASA_ACTION_SERVER
    ...
    :RUN_RASA_ACTION_SERVER
    start cmd.exe /k call conda activate %env% ^&^& cd.. ^&^& call rasa run actions
    CLS
    GOTO MENU
```

In this part I start an action server running on port 5055 in a new cmd terminal. 
I also want to kill the task via my terminal menu.

so here is what I got so far:

```
...
ECHO 6 - Kill Rasa Action Server
...
IF %M%==6 GOTO KILL_RASA_ACTION_SERVER
...
:KILL_RASA_ACTION_SERVER
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr "5055" ') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine



:SkipLine                                                                              
taskkill /f /pid %ProcessId%
CLS
GOTO MENU
```

This is working fine, BUT...the previously opened terminal is still open, I want to kill the task and close the cmd terminal after that.

How can I achieve this? I tried an `EXIT` but I always close the main terminal menu.

Comment: which previously opened terminal? the one you're attempting to kill? `for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr "5055" ') do taskkill /f /pid %%a`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes exactly, I type the number 2 in the main console, a new terminal opens in which the server starts, after a while I will shut down the server, I type 6 in the main menu and the  new cmd in which the server was started should close

Comment: ok, so try `for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr "5055" ') do taskkill /f /pid %%a`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard i tried this but unfortunately it closes the 'main menu terminal', I want to close the other one.

Comment: Then you need to determine the pid of that terminal

Comment: you mean using tasklist instead of netstat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The previously opened terminal is still open, I want to kill the task and close the cmd terminal after that.

Set a Window Title for the Shell Window you are opening

```cmd
SET /P env=your conda env:    
 REM ...
ECHO 2 - Run Rasa Action Server
 REM ...
IF %M%==2 GOTO RUN_RASA_ACTION_SERVER
 REM ...
:RUN_RASA_ACTION_SERVER
start "KILL_ME_PLEASE" cmd.exe /k call conda activate %env% ^&^& cd.. ^&^& call rasa run actions
CLS
GOTO MENU
```

Then in your Other section you just find the CMD window with that title and kill it and any process it spawned.

```cmd
 REM ...
ECHO 6 - Kill Rasa Action Server
 REM ...
IF %M%==6 GOTO KILL_RASA_ACTION_SERVER
 REM ...
:KILL_RASA_ACTION_SERVER
FOR /F "Tokens=2" %%_ IN ('
  TaskList -v /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" ^| FIND "KILL_ME_PLEASE"
') DO (
  TaskKill /T /F /PID %%_
)
CLS
GOTO MENU
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I need!

Comment: @mexwell Glad to help!